# Python - can not delete, then create folder

Tags: python, permissions, mkdir, spyder

I am writing a Python script that checks if a folder exists, deleting it if it does, and then rewrites it.

I can create a directory, then immediately delete it.

But when I try to delete a directory, then create one, I get the following error:

```
"[Error 5] Access is denied: 'plots'"
```

While:

```
os.path.exists(dir)=false
```

Perhaps Spyder is reserving the memory somehow? Please help!

```
import os, shutil

dir = 'plots'
print "remove directory"
if os.path.exists(dir):
  shutil.rmtree(dir)
print os.path.exists(dir)

print "create directory"
os.mkdir(dir, 0755)
print os.path.exists(dir)
```

EDIT:

**Output first run** (when 'plots' doesn't exist)

remove directory

False

create directory

True

**Output second run** (when 'plots' does exist)

remove directory

False

create directory

File "C:/Python27/Spyder Workspace/JPL_impact_gnuplot/07gnuplot/02my_lammps_anal/anal_lammps.py", line 60, in 
    os.mkdir(dir, 0755)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: 'plots'"

So, at the end:
   os.path.exists(dir)=false
But access to that dir is surprisingly denied! Help!

Comment: What output do you get when you run this?

Comment: It runs fine on my computer: `remove directory
False
create directory
True`

Comment: What "memory" do you think is in a directory?

Comment: Could you try to introduce a sleep of a couple of seconds before creating the dir again?

Comment: @drodri, good suggestion, sleep doesn't help though!

Comment: Works here fine too (win 7, python 2.7). Which is your system? Do you have antivirus?

Comment: It also works fine here on my Ubuntu 12.04 + Python 2.7.

Comment: @kindall

Suppose that we reverse the order of the code, create a directory and then remove it. That works fine, no problems whatsoever. 

In this case, we have a directory that exists, we try to remove it. This appears to happen, as there is no path to the directory, (os.path.exists(dir)=false). But now, when we try to write to create this directory permission is denied! Permission is actually denied wherever the file is viewed (i.e. win explorer, project explorer, etc.). When Spyder is closed, the directory vanishes. My current leading theory is that the directory is deleted, but reserved.

Comment: Possibly Spyder has made the directory current or something. In Windows you can't delete the current directory.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys. In a linux environment, this isn't a problem, so this is specific to the Spyder IDE. Comments on how to fix this still very much appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if this is helpful, but I couldn't use `0755`, only `755`. Perhaps try doing `os.mkdir(dir, 755)` instead.

Comment: @bourbaki4481472 Thanks for the suggestion. Doesn't change anything for me, although I do generally use 755 on linux machines

Comment: @kindall Yes! That is it. Any removed directories must be outside of the current directory. Thanks!

Comment: (*Spyder dev here*) @DanielBrooks, maybe you made the `plots` dir the current directory one by selecting it in the our File Explorer. I can't think of any other way Spyder can make that happen ;-)

Comment: @CarlosCordoba Yes, that was it! When I moved the plots directory outside of the current directory, the program ran smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your environment does not have write permissions to the directory.

You can recreate the scenario from the command line.

```
$ touch testfile
$ ls testfile
testfile
$ chmod 555 .
$ rm testfile
$ ls testfile
ls: cannot access testfile: No such file or directory
$ touch testfile
touch: cannot touch `testfile': Permission denied
```